# Big Endianness vs Little Endinness in multi word objects

Tags: mips, endianness, memory-address, mips32

I know difference between Big Endianness and Little Endianness in single word(4-bytes) variables such as Int32.
I want to know If we have multi word variables or object (e.g. two word variable Int64) with the following data in Little Endianness format:

```
----------------->
Lower Memory Address to Higher Memory Address
b0 b1 b2 b3 |b4 b5 b6 b7 (b means byte)
word0       |word1
```

Which of these below structures is the way that Big Endianness will store it in memory? (Our memory is 32 bit bandwidth and byte addressable, word accessible  and architecture is MIPS)
structure 1:

```
----------------->
Lower Memory Address to Higher Memory Address
b3 b2 b1 b0 |b7 b6 b5 b4
word0       |word1
```

structure 2:

```
----------------->
Lower Memory Address to Higher Memory Address
b7 b6 b5 b4 |b3 b2 b1 b0
word0       |word1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I asked a professor, it seems like structure1 is the right answer.